# ngx-translate does not show translated text

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

i'm using `@ngx-translate/core@12.1.2` and i have configured the app like this,

`app.module.ts`

```
...
TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    }),
....
```

`app.component.ts`

```
...
this.translate.addLangs(['en']);
    this.translate.setDefaultLang('en');
    this.translate.use('en');
...
```

`en.json`

```
{
    "home": {
        "menu": "Menu {{value}}",
        "search": "Search"
    }
}
```

and the component which use the translation,

```
this.translate.get('home.menu', {value: 'Hey !'}).subscribe((resul: string) => {
  console.log('Translations', resul);
});

console.log('Translate instant ', this.translate.instant('home.menu'));
```

And it prints only this , `Translations home.menu`.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

did you create your main(not translate) language json file?
try to create that file exactlly same as en.json files structure